# Rals concatenate attribute in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This query selects a printer (record in db)

```
@printer_receipt = Printer.where(print_receipts: 1)
```

I want to concatenate the attribute

```
@printer_receipt.printer_position
```

to:

```
printer = CupsPrinter.new(printers)
```

to select correct printer to execute a job.

To have something like:

```
printer = CupsPrinter.new(printers.@printer_receipt.printer_position)
```

which should return:

```
  printer = CupsPrinter.new(printers.first)
```

assuming

```
@printer_receipt.printer_position = first
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: How does the attributes of CupsPrinter look like? Are you just trying to create a new object of CupsPrinter something like this 
`CupsPrinter.new(printer_position: @printer_receipt.printer_position)`

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I'm 95% sure you're misunderstanding how all of this works. If you write out `printers.@printer_receipt.printer_position` by hand (instead of having it "magically concatenated"), does it work?

Comment: Sorry I updated the question

Comment: From this small amount of code we see, `@printer_receipt` appears to be an active relation. And `printer_position` looks like an attribute on a printer. So `@printer_receipt.printer_position` will crash with a NoMethodError

Comment: printer_position is db column.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  no printers.@printer_receipt.printer_position does not work..